# I don't have idea how to configure FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, windows-forms-designer

I tell you my problem. I have different [5] DataGridView with a FlowLayoutPanel.

The problem is that, I do not know how to make the DataGredView touch the wall on the right. I have tried modifying the "Anchor" attribute and it does not work.

[The space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1bw0.png)

[the attributes of FlowLayoutPanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YLP2.png)

Comment: @TimWilliams Thanks for the edit, but any ideas?

Comment: You don't need a `FlowLayoutPanel`, it's enough to add your control to a `Panel` and set their `Dock` to `Top`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dock property instead, so it fills the space.
Update:
Link to example:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-anchor-and-dock-child-controls-in-a-flowlayoutpanel-control

Comment: If I modify the dock to fill (of flowLayoutPanel), the other elements disappear (buttons, editText ...) and if I put it to the dgv it "disappears"

Comment: I meant the dock property of the child controls of the dockPanel. I will update my answer with a link to an example.